# Explicit solution to Poisson equation on torus

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, poissons-equation

I am studying the Vlasov-Poisson system on a torus in three dimensions, $\mathbb{T}^3$. I consider a constant mass density $\rho = C$. What is a solution to the Poisson equation $\Delta U = 4\pi\rho $ for this mass density? Unfortunately, I am not used to working with a torus.

Is a solution just
\begin{align}
U = \frac{2\pi}{3}C \,x^2 
\end{align}
or is this just the case for $\mathbb{R^3}$? Please let me know if something about my question is unclear. Thank you!

Comment: If the mass density is constant, then isn't $\rho - \bar \rho$ 0?

Comment: You are right. In the case of a homogeneous distribution, I dont need to substract the mean value. I can work with $\Delta U = 4\pi \rho $ instead. I'm gonna edit this in the question.

Comment: No, you're right that you need to subtract the mean for it to be solvable on a torus.  I was just trying to point out that the equation should be trivial to solve since $\Delta U = 0$.

Comment: So in contrast to $\mathbb{R}^3$, the Poisson equation for a constant density is always trivial on the torus? Is the solution then $U= C  x$?  Shouldn't it be periodic in some way?

Comment: Can I clarify when you say "in three dimensions" do you mean the 3-torus i.e. $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$ or the 2-torus but living in three dimensional Euclidean space?

Comment: I mean $\mathbb{T}^3$.